# how to link to edit_post_path from index page for a simple Rails blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

EDIT: I found a similar thread, my apologies for not being able to find it earlier. Will follow advice from this thread:

[How to route from a nested resource in rails? Getting 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737339/how-to-route-from-a-nested-resource-in-rails-getting-activerecordrecordnotfo)

EDIT2: Ahhh, I found this in a similar thread:

> this is because of the <%= link_to "Edit", edit_game_path(:id) %> call in the layout template. Which is misplaced. You cannot edit if you are viewing /games because no :id is present.

gotcha. I need to make a find_id method don't I? Will keep this answer updated

---

I'm following along a basic rails tutorial for a blog

I have defined the edit and update features in the posts_controller:

> def edit
>         @post = Post.find(params[:id])
>     end
>
> def update
>         @post = Post.find(params[:id])
>
> ```
>   if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))  
>       redirect_to @post
>   else  
>       render 'edit'  
>   end
> ```
>
> end

and linking to the edit_path in the show page (localhost:3000/posts/1) works just fine (it goes to http://localhost:3000/posts/1/edit):

> 

but when I put the same code in the index page underneath each post, the url it tries to redirect to is

> http://localhost:3000/posts/%23%3CPost::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xd0a2518%3E/edit

so obviously there's an issue with it grabbing the correct id. instead of %23%3CPost::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xd0a2518%3E, it should just grab the id of the post that is to be edited.

It's probably a really easy fix, but as you can tell I'm fairly new. Thanks in advance. Oh and can someone also explain where "params" comes from? How come I didn't have to define this? I defined post_params in the private section of the posts_controller, but what is params? Maybe I'll just google that. confused what:

> if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))

actually means. I get that it's a boolean whether or not it updates, but not sure what the paramater for update is. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a game in the show action if you pulled the game previous from your DB.

When you show the game/s you render each game

```
def index
 @game = Game.all
end
```

This loops through all your games and renders them all using a game template or partial. (view/games/_game.erb)

Each game knows its own ID. so all you have to do is inside that partial to call the edit_path

```
edit_game_path(@game)
```

and it will take you to the edit page of that specific game.